# Fires Intent with four option for sending email

Tags: android

I write a code that fires an `Intent` for sending an email.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_title_text)));
```

However, when this `Intent` is fired, I see many items on the list like Bluetooth, Gmail app, Facebook app and so on.

How can I filter this list and only show these four items:
**Gmail, EverNote, Twitter and Facebook.**

Answer (score 0):

you can't control the application list, in fact every application that register for Intent `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND` will be shown in this list